# Getting error on start fedora and taking me to emergency mode

Tags: fedora, grub, initramfs

When I am Starting my fedora pc it gives me a console. I am getting a big mess. I entered the password and I ran `systemctl` command and I checked that it was unable to start `initrd-switch-root.service` and `systemd-modules-load.service` and many directories like /boot and /home were unavailable  -

[image: weird screen]

[image: error grub fedora]

Comment: Did you enter the root password to open a shell and look at the logs to see what's happening? Until you do that, there's nothing that anyone can suggest.

Comment: I entered password and I ran systemctl command and I  checked that it was unable to start initrd-switch-root.service and systemd-modules-load.service and many directorys like /boot and /home were unavailable

Comment: Reinstall from scratch. I don't know what you're doing to it but you continuously damage it beyond repair.

Comment: I dont have installation any media

Comment: I had solved this by loading kernel modules & mounting /sysroot directory in read write mode but I got emergency console again and again, I have always to load kernel modules and mount /sysroot directory to start my pc . How do I get rid of this?